# Uncaught TypeError in Bootstrap tagsinput using typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

```
$('#keyword').tagsinput({
      typeahead: {
        minLength: 1,
        source: function(query, process) {
          var search = getautocomplete();
          //alert(search);
          if (search == '') { alert('Select Date'); }
          else 
          {
            $.getJSON( search, {
              format: "json"
              })
            .done(function( data ) {
                var suggestions = [];
                $aaaa = '';
                $.each( data.counts.tagfields.content_autosuggest, function( i, suggestTerm ) {
                  if ($.isNumeric(suggestTerm)) {} else  { suggestions.push(suggestTerm); }
                });
                process(suggestions);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

The code works fine with Typeahead alone. But when i add tagsinput feature into it, it gives the following error in the Chrome Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

getautocomplete() function gives a URL which is passed into getJSON and the data received from getJSON is passed into the .done function which parses the JSON and gets the tags I require.

The tags are being added properly to "suggestions" variable but it shows error at process(suggestions)